# Intellisense in Xamarin studio with .axml?

Tags: xamarin, intellisense, xamarin-studio

Xml files in Xamarin studio are not supported by intellisense it seems, I'm talking about layout files (.axml) and normal .xml files. Is there a way to add intellisense support to these files?

I'm not a "drag n drop" person, and working directly with xml is a nightmare in Xamarin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must close file and open with RigthClick file(in Solution pad)->Open With->Source Code Editor.
More info on this [forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2298/axml-intellisense).